# Problem with retrieving primary value

Tags: php

I have a table `t_s_list` having `s_id` as primary key. Now I want to retrieve primary value if the corresponding column is already inserted. If the corresponding column is instantly I can easily get the values using `mysql_insert_id` function. But what should if value is already exist.

NOTE: If I want to get the primary values of already exist column I am getting value as `Resource id #5` as result.

My code is..

```
if($txtbx1!="") {
$result=mysql_query("select title from t_s_list where title='$txtbx1'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
    $resultid=mysql_query("select s_id from t_s_list where title='$txtbx1'");
    print_r($resultid); }

    else
    {
    $insert=mysql_query("Insert into t_s_list(title) values ('$txtbx1') ");
    $resultid=mysql_insert_id();
    print_r($resultid);
    }
}
else    {
    $msg="Text box empty";
}
```

Comment: what's the logic behind the first two queries? first one is useless

Comment: First one is for checking if title is exist or not and if it is existing than I am selecting corresponding primary key value.

Comment: first one checks, second one retrieves. Just use the second one.

Comment: First one is checking if same title field is already exist or not. If it is existing than its s_id is retrieved if not existing than firstly it is inserted than retrieved. ...I am not getting what u exactly want to say...

Comment: think about it. if you execute the second query you both get whether that title exists and if exists the value for s_id.

Comment: GOT IT... Apply second one directly. and checking using `mysql_num_row` if retrieving 0 than applying insertion. Correct..? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("select s_id from t_s_list where title='$txtbx1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$resultid = $row['sid'];
print_r($resultid);
```

Comment: Whats need of mysql_fetch_assoc function, when I am directly selecting s_id from query. Please elaborate.

Comment: mysql_query doesn't recognize that you only fetch one column. It gets a result set from the database which it is up to you to work with. This result set is identical in structure for all SELECT queries.

Answer (score 1):

Emil is correct, 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
mysql_query returns a [Resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) not a string or integer.

There are many ways to access the results table from the resource. 
mysql_fetch_assoc() will return an associative array where the column heads are used to read the given value. 
i.e. $resource = mysql_query(...); $results = mysql_fetch_assoc(); $id = $results["columnIdentifier"];
mysql_fetch_array() will return an array of values
i.e. $resource = mysql_query(...); $results = mysql_fetch_array(); $id = $results[0]; *assuming the id is the first element returned on the table*

Comment: you could also try, 
$results = mysql_query(...sql SELECT...);
if(!$results)
{
$results = mysql_query(...sql INSERT with SELECT..);
}
$myTable = mysql_fetch_array($results);
$id = $myTable[0]; // 0 assumed you are returning the id column first